# What does this regular expression mean: [^\(\)]*?

Tags: python, regex, expression

I wanted to understand this regular expression in Python: `\([^\(\)]*\`

The full code is below. It reverses text inside of parentheses.

```
import re

def reverseParentheses(s):
    s_new = s
    count = 0
    while True:
        mat = re.findall(r'\([^\(\)]*\)',s_new)
        if not mat:
            break
        for i in mat:
            temp = re.sub(r'\(|\)', '', i)
            s_new = re.sub(re.escape(i), temp[::-1], s_new)
    return(s_new)
```

Comment: Enter this expression at https://regex101.com/, for example. It'll give you the step-by-step explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break it:

```
\(   \)
Start with ( and ends with )

[]*
^ A char that is part of the char-group any number of times.

^
^ Not one of the following chars

\(\)
^ ( or ) - because they appear inside the char-group
```

So basically if we take this:

```
[^\(\)]*
^ Any char that is not ( and not ), any number of times.
```

And if we combine all of the above we get something like:

> A string that starts with `(` followed by any char that is not `(` and not `)` and ends with `)`

Answer (score 0):

\ usually is associate with d, or some other character that represents a decimal or some other type of literal. In this case it just means the literal '('

r'\(' >>> r(

[] is a bracket that represents any set of strings (i.e. [abc] would represent anything from either a,b, or c

^ something anchored to beginning of the string set (i.e. ^a would look for no a in string)
[^abc] looks for not a or b or c
or in this case not the literal ( and not the literal )

- represents that the pattern is matched either 0,1,2,3... or more times

'\)' >>> )

an example: r( ) is the minimum

r(())))) would fail

r(((((() would fail

r( ) ) would fail because as you can see [^()] is anchored

r(  *LITERALLY ANYTHING EXCEPT '(' or ')'*  )

Comment: beat me to it ^